# looping over 2 dictionaries to find the number of subsequent dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of objects

```
dictionary['A'].objects
```

Each of these object dictionaries ('a', 'b', 'c', etc.) contain a dictionary of attributes

```
dictionary['A'].objects['a'].attributes
```

What I'd like to do is take all the attribute dictionaries for a given object and create a new dictionary. This new master dictionary of all the attributes needs to only contain the existing values from the attribute dictionaries, including duplicates. There will be duplicate keys, which can't happen in a dictionary, so I need to create new arbitrary keys for each value (1,2,3, or something).

Update:

This is what i'm currently doing to create a list of strings. For whatever reason, I lose the elements in the list when I go to manipulate it. len(listA), in that place in the code, returns 0. If I push it into the second for loop, it will stay populated. However, then I terminate the for loop early and don't get any subsequent dictionaries of attributes. That's why i've been rethinking what to do and perhaps my issue has to do with the use of a list.

```
    listA = []

    for objectsA in dictionary.objects:
        thisObjectA = dictionary.objects[objectsA]

        for attributesA in thisObjectA.attributes:
            listA.append(attributesA + " " + thisObjectA.attributes[attributesA])


    len(listA)
```

Comment: Could you provide example input/output? Also - if you're going to *create new arbitrary keys for each value* what's the point of having a `dict` ?

Comment: I agree, I was about to suggest maybe a list of tuples instead

Comment: I've updated my post; I've tried using a list of strings and am getting weird behavior and I haven't figured out why. Perhaps the for loops or the way i'm populating the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just decoded your code and made this snippet, if this not working kindly let me now

```
sample_data = {'dictA': {'dictA1': 'A'}, 'dictB': {'dictB1': 'B'}}

listA = []

for key in sample_data.keys():
    new_data = sample_data[key]
    for key1 in new_data.keys():
        listA.append(key1 + " " + new_data[key1])

print(listA)
print(len(listA))
```

Comment: thanks @vijayanandrp , this works similar to my code. My issue is if I add something like 'test = 100 / len(listA)' , I get a 'division by 0' error. It seems like I'm losing the information in my list somehow.

Comment: okay. In that case, add few conditions like `len(listA) == 0` make it as `1` to avoid exception and also add extra list variable to be the backup of values.

Comment: It turned out to be something outside of this code all together; I appreciate the help though.